# Issues graduating to AVR-C

Tags: c, atmega328, avr, avrdude, arduinoisp

I'm trying to make the transition from coding in the Arduino language to AVR-C, but I'm having some issues with my microcontrollers.

I don't have an ISP, so I'm using one of my Arduino UNOs with the ArduinoISP sketch. The problem is that when I try to run avrdude it gives me this error:

```
avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
  Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
  this check.
```

However, when I try to run the command with the sugested -F it uploads the code to the Arduino UNO I'm using as an ISP instead of the ATmega328p on my breadboard.

Does anyone have any idea about whats going on here, or how to fix it?

Comment: Have you disabled reset on your Arduino?

Comment: @Majenko I don't think so, how?

Comment: You would know if you had, so you obviously haven't. Add a 10uF capacitor between reset and gnd on the Arduino.

Comment: will a 1uF or 50uF capacitor work?

Comment: 1uF might. 50uF will.

Comment: Note that switching to writing in plain C doesn't mean you have to change the method you use to get code into the chip - you can still use the Arduino bootloader.  And of course you can also use ISP to load Arduino sketches - the sources used to *generate* hex files and the process of *loading* them into the target are orthogonal subjects.

Comment: This does not seem to work, the arduino still resets, and i get the same error. I'v tried with 1uF and 50uF between reset and gnd, and with 120 ohm between reset and 5V

Comment: @Majenko ok, so now i tried with a 1000uF, this time there was a difference atleast, now i get the error "avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00" instead...

Comment: Note the baud rate of the ISP sketch will probably differ from that of the bootloader (often this is intentional, to make sure that the wrong target will not be programmed).  Your question should really include your full avrdude command line.

Comment: avrdude -c avrisp -p atmega328 -P /dev/tty.wchusbserial1410 -U flash:w:main.hex
This one?

Comment: [THERE IS NO ARDUINO LANGUAGE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!](https://hackaday.com/2015/07/28/embed-with-elliot-there-is-no-arduino-language/)

Comment: This is nothing to do with languages. *I'm trying to make the transition from coding in the Arduino language to AVR-C, but I'm having some issues with my microcontrollers.* You have a problem uploading your code, that is all. Since this question has been abandoned by the OP I'm going to close it.

Comment: Just read the arduino source and libraries, they provide an abstraction layer to AVR-C.

Answer (score 0):

"invalid device signature" is due to bad connection or inability to reset the device (RST pin fuse setting for example).